# Adding new input field to product insert form Opencart

Tags: php, csv, opencart

I need to add a custom file input field to its own tab in Opencart product insert/add form in Opencart, to upload a csv file into mysql database. I have added the tab/field to the view file, updated the language files, but am unsure of what I need to do exactly in the controller, and model in order to pass the data from the uploaded csv into the database table.

The `product_pins` table:

```
pin_id (AI) | pin_product_id | pin_pin_number
```

The csv file data(example):

```
342353535345
345345346346
235434534634
```

Where I am so far:

**Controller** `admin/controller/catalog/product.php` (around line 807):

```
if (isset($this->request->post['product_pins']) ) {
    $this->data['product_pins'] = is_uploaded_file($this->request->post['product_pins']);
} else {
    $this->data['product_pins'] = '';
}
```

**Model** `admin/model/catalog/product.php` (around line 7):

```
if ( isset($this->data['product_pins']) ) {
    $handle = fopen($this->data['product_pins'], "r");
    while (($pins = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        foreach ($pins as $pin) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_pins SET pin_product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', pin_pin_number = '" . $this->db->escape($pin) . "'");
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: hi, could you post a link or at least a pastebin of the generated html, my  guess is that it's something simple, because opencart fieldnames don't have any major tricks.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens when you try to input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - the CSV handling part should be within a controller, not in the model class. Models (when speaking of right MVC) should only retrieve or set the data and pass them to or that are passed from the controller - that should then manipulate and control them and forward to or get from the frontend view (template).

Secondly: submitted files in OpenCart are present in the `$this->request->files` array.

Finally: the method `is_uploaded_file()` returns `boolean` value, thus I do not know how could You be parsing `boolean` and create a file handle from it.

So, let's take a look at it... Try the code below.

**Controller:**

```
if (is_uploaded_file($this->request->files['product_pins']['tmp_name'])) {
    $handle = fopen($this->request->files['product_pins']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while (($pins = fgetcsv($handle, 50, ",")) !== false) { // If we know there is only a 10 chars PIN per line it is better to lower the expected line length to lower the memory consumption...
       $this->data['product_pins'][] = $pins; // there is only one PIN per line
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
   $this->data['product_pins'] = array();
}
```

Now You (should) have all the PINs from the CSV file added to `$this->data['product_pins']` array - and assuming You are then passing `$this->data` to the model, it should contain this code:

**Model:**

```
if (!empty($this->data['product_pins'])) {
    foreach ($this->data['product_pins'] as $pin) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_pins SET pin_product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', pin_pin_number = '" . $this->db->escape($pin) . "'");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...